# How to get specific HTML element under current WebElement

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

After i found specific `WebElement` and do all my stuff (clicks etc.) is it possible to get let say another `WebElement` under this `WebElement` that i already have without `FindElement` again ?

For example:

```
WebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("..."));
```

Now i know that under this `element` i have lats say `dpan` that i want so is it possible to reach this `span` from that `element` i already found ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WebElement interface also has a [findElement](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29) method that can be used to find an element relative to one that has already been found.

Here's an example implementation of it:

```
// Find the parent element
WebElement parentElement = driver.findElement(By.id("parent")); 

// Find the child element relative to the parent element
WebElement childElement  = parentElement.findElement(By.id("child"));
```

Answer (score 1):

it will be better if u give ur html code portion. From my guess, lets say u have html code like this:

```
div id = "one"
  span
  span
```

now if u want to access the 2nd span element, use

```
cssSelector
```

and inside this, write code like this:

```
By.cssSelector("#one.span:nth-child(2)")
```

here

```
# is used for id
```